# Child Package for a package in PHP (Subpackage)

Tags: php, composer-php

I have written a class (alpha.php) which makes uses another package ( Package Name: somepackage). As always i used composer to install the package (somepackage) and used `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` to load the package in my class.

Now i am planning to make the class (alpha.php) i have written as a package to be shared with my friend. How can i use (Package Name: somepackage) now? I can no longer use `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php` in my class alpha.php.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should only include the autoload, if your package is a full codebase, the sort used with the `composer create-project` command.

If your package is to be used by other codebases you need not worry, and leave the autoloading up to them.